# Render Url is not Working

Tags: java, liferay

whenever i'm including one portlet into another portlet jsp by using liferay-portlet:runtime tag **at that time included portlet is not taking render params to the controller**.

```
 <portlet:renderURL var="addCategoryURL">
            <portlet:param name="tabs" value="one"></portlet:param>
    </portlet:renderURL>

    <aui:a href="<%= addCategoryURL.toString() %>">click</aui:a>
    System.out.println(ParamUtil.getString(request, "tabs"));
```

Comment: Pls post the URL from the browser after the click...

Comment: http://localhost:8080/group/g-classroom/administrator?p_p_id=feedbackcategories_WAR_FeedbackManagementSystemportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=2&_feedbackcategories_WAR_FeedbackManagementSystemportlet_%3Cportlet%3Anamespace%2F%3Etabs=one

Comment: I assume that you are running 6.2. What exact version?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run this code.

```
<portlet:renderURL var="addCategoryURL">
        <portlet:param name="tabs" value="one"/>    
</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%= addCategoryURL.toString() %>">click</a>
```

The parameter seems to be wrongly encoded. The namespace part should not be there.

&_feedbackcategories_WAR_FeedbackManagementSystemportlet_**%3Cportlet%3Anamespace%2F%3E**tabs=one